# About JavaScript events and mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Let us consider we have save button in layout.
I have two popups which appears on clicking two different links and save button is common for both the popups
How to trigger two different events using same button on two different popups?

Comment: while calling button's  click event function pass flag as parameters.

Comment: Too many unknowns here without some more specific code samples

Answer (score 0):

You Can bind two  Different click event to save button on click event of 2 different popups.
eg :

```
function tabClick(evt, tabName) {
      if (tabName == "Tab1") 
        {
                        $("#btnSave").prop('title', 'Tab1 Save');
                        $("#btnSave").off('click');
                        $("#btnSave").on('click', function () { Tab1Func() });
       }
        else if (tabName == "Tab2") {
                        $("#btnSave").prop('title', 'Tab2 Save');
                        $("#btnSave").off('click');
                        $("#btnSave").on('click', function () { Tab2Func() });
         }
}
```

on click event of popup call above code.